# Enable chrome extention for hosts only

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hi I'm creating my first chrome extension here is my minifest file

```
{
  "name": "Get pages source",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Get pages source from a popup",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "images/get_started16.png",
      "32": "images/get_started32.png",
      "48": "images/get_started48.png",
      "128": "images/get_started128.png"
    },
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/get_started16.png",
    "32": "images/get_started32.png",
    "48": "images/get_started48.png",
    "128": "images/get_started128.png"
  },
  "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>"]
}
```

I want to disable the extension for all urls other than few lets say I just want to enable my extension only for yahoo.com and stackoverflow.com what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `matches` in your manifest.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#declaratively

For example:

```
{
  "name": "Get pages source",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Get pages source from a popup",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "images/get_started16.png",
      "32": "images/get_started32.png",
      "48": "images/get_started48.png",
      "128": "images/get_started128.png"
    },
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/get_started16.png",
    "32": "images/get_started32.png",
    "48": "images/get_started48.png",
    "128": "images/get_started128.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
   {
     "matches": ["http://*.yahoo.com*", "http://*.stackoverflow.com*"]
   }
  ],
  "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>"]
}
```

Btw. avoid `all_urls` permission if don't need it.